# How to bind to radiobutton selected property in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, radio-button

Using visual studio 2015 community, and .NET 4.5

I have a dynamic list of radio buttons that are specific to a user of my app.  When the user authenticates with a web service, the button list is dynamically created.  The list is list is stored in an ObservableCollection.  I have bound this to the the XAML and it renders correctly, and it correctly stores the isSelected correctly after selection.

What i want to do is to have an event trigger when the user selects a service type (clicks a radio button).  I have read a lot of examples, but they hard-code radio buttons, but in my case I need the buttons to be dynamic.

How do I bind a button click in a XAML to the ViewModel?

ServiceCost.cs

```
public class ServiceCost
{
    public long pst_id { get; set; }
    public string pst_description_short { get; set; }
    public decimal pst_cost { get; set; }
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set{if (value != _isSelected) { _isSelected = value; } }
    }
    public string DescriptionPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(Strings.ServiceCost_DescriptionPrice, this.pst_description_short, pst_cost.ToString());
        } 
    }
 ...
```

xaml:

```
  ...
  <GroupBox
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      Grid.Column="2"
      FontWeight="Bold"
      Header="Select Service Type"
      Margin="0,7,0,0"
      Padding="2">
        <ItemsControl FontWeight="Normal" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServiceTypes}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton
                          Content="{Binding Path=DescriptionPrice}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"
                          GroupName="ServiceType"
                          Margin="2,3.5"
                          />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </GroupBox>
    ...
```

ViewModel:

```
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<ServiceCost> _serviceTypes;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceCost> ServiceTypes
    {
        get { return _serviceTypes; }
        set
        {
            if (_serviceTypes != value)
            {
                _serviceTypes = value;
                DynamicOnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to do this in XAML only. If so, using an `EventTrigger` is the way to go.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton Margin="2,3.5"
                     Content="{Binding Path=DescriptionPrice}"
                     GroupName="ServiceType"
                     IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}">
            <RadioButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                </EventTrigger>
            </RadioButton.Triggers>
        </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Note that RadioButton's `Checked` event is accessibly through its base class `ToggleButton`. If you need to call code on this event, you can try [this technique](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/using-eventtrigger-in-xaml-for-mvvm-no.html).

Comment: thanks for your help, but without more to go on, I couldn't get the event triggers to work in my code, at least I couldn't make them bind to the viewmodel, the worked to the serviceCost class, but that didn't help.  The example enc. did something to break my project when I tried to install those external references, and I couldn't understand where it was breaking...

Comment: Perhaps this might be more useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42134/RadioListBox-A-ListBox-with-Radio-Buttons-WPF-Vers

Answer (score 0):

The problem i was having was getting access the viewModel after a radio button click.  After a lot of searching, I found that a ListBox was a way of wrapping the radiobuttons in such a way that it had a selectedItem, I could then binding the selectedItem of the listbox to my ViewModel and have access to the variable.  I don't know if this is the best way to get it working, but it does work for me.

ServiceCost.cs = unchanged.

xaml:

```
...
    <GroupBox
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
      Grid.Column="2"
      FontWeight="Bold"
      Header="Select Service Type"
      Margin="0,7,0,0"
      Padding="2" >
        <ListBox  Margin="0,10,0,10" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceCosts}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedServiceCost}" >
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <RadioButton Content="{Binding DescriptionPrice}"
                       IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Margin="0,5,0,5"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </GroupBox>
    ...
```

the viewModel:

```
    ...
    private ObservableCollection<ServiceCost> _serviceCosts;
    public ObservableCollection<ServiceCost> ServiceCosts
    {
        get { return _serviceCosts; }
        set { if (_serviceCosts != value){_serviceCosts = value;    DynamicOnPropertyChanged();}}
    }

    private ServiceCost _selectedServiceCost;
    public ServiceCost SelectedServiceCost
    {
        get { return _selectedServiceCost; }
        set
        { 
            if (_selectedServiceCost != value)
            {
                // This is what I needed access to:  do something here!.
                _selectedServiceCost = value;
                DynamicOnPropertyChanged(); 
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```